# What's the meaning of "It came right as"?

Tags: phrases

> It came right as president Trump and the Japanese Prime minister were sitting down for dinner at the president's private resor Mar-aLago in Palm Beach, Florida.

In this sentence, What's the meaning of "It came right? as"? I couldn't find the meaning of it in some of dictionaries

Comment: What meaning could you find in the other dictionaries?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/right adverb, 1.1 and 1.2 both apply for example.

Comment: Often such questions arise from breaking the phrase in the wrong place.  Here, *came right* is not a meaningful phrase (though you might reasonably think it is); the relevant phrase is *right as*.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *"it came right as"* implies that one action (**it**) had just occurred at the same time another event is still taking place. It's a bit difficult to explain in the abstract, so let me provide a few examples of its usage:

Here's a rather simple one. If I say *"The apple fell from the tree right as I was coming outside"*, this means that at the same point in time that I was coming outside, the apple had just fallen from the tree.

If I say *"I had finished my homework right as the dog started barking"*, it means that at the same point in time that I had just finished my homework, the dog then started to bark.

In your example, the first action that was just completed is unspecified, probably given in an exterior context. The ongoing action is that "President Trump and the Japanese Minister were sitting down for dinner at the presiden's resort".

Comment: The point was, he could have got that meaning from a dictionary fairly easily, and saying he "couldn't find the meaning of it in ***some*** dictionaries" sounded like a plea for something different. No sign of actual effort.

Comment: "It came right as" is a bit of an idiomatic expression that would be difficult to understand as a L2 speaker, and likely not in a normal dictionary. So I see no problem with providing an answer.

Comment: It's the "teach them to fish" bit :o) I'm often - usually - on the "answer" rather than "complain" side myself, just thought this one was a bit too easy(!). Sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's a totally fair point to bring up.